# Number of functions $:\{1,2,3,\ldots,2k+1\}\to \{1,2,3,\ldots,2n+1\}$ satisfying a certain conditions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $k<n$ be positive integers. I wish to count the number of function  $:\{1,2,3,\ldots,2k+1\}\to \{1,2,3,\ldots,2n+1\}$ for which $f(k+1)\neq 2n-2$,
$$
f(1)<f(2)<\ldots<f(k)<f(k+1)>f(k+2)>\ldots>f(2 k)>f(2 k+1),
$$
and $f(a)\neq f(b)$ for any $a\neq b$ belong to $\{1,2,3,\ldots,2k+1\}$.

My approach: $S_1$ be the set of all functions for which $f(1)<f(2)<\ldots<f(k)<f(k+1)$,  and $f(k+1)\neq 2n-2$. Then $|S_1|=\binom{2n+1}{k+1}-\binom{2n-3}{k}$.

Similar: $S_2$ be the set of all functions for which $f(k+1)>f(k+2)>\ldots>f(2 k)>f(2 k+1)$,  and $f(k+1)\neq 2n-2$, then $|S_2|=\binom{2n+1}{k+1}-\binom{2n-3}{k}$.

Now I wish to find $|S_1\cap S_2|$. This seems IE principle could help, but I don't know how to apply it here? Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need IE. Clearly $f(k+1)>2k$. Choose a number $f(k+1)>2k, f(k+1)\ne 2n-2$ first, then the first $k$ and then the last $k$ numbers $f(i)<f(k+1)$ separately. There are $2n-2k$ choices for $a=f(2k+1)=2k+1,....,2n-3,2n-1, 2n, 2n+1$. For each choice of $a$ there are ${a-1\choose k}$ choices of the first $k$ numbers, and ${a-1-k\choose k}$ choices of the last $k$ numbers. So the result is

$$\sum_{a=2k+1}^{2n+1}{a-1\choose k}{a-1-k\choose k}-{2n-3\choose k}{2n-3-k\choose k}.$$

Comment: thanks markvs, very nice!